# How to find quarter stemp diff by sql please?

Tags: mysql, sql, timestampdiff

I use mysql, and these time columns are not all in the same year.

I use this:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(QUARTER, DATE_FORMAT('2018-03-30', '%Y-%m-%d'), DATE_FORMAT('2018-09-30', '%Y-%m-%d'))
FROM DUAL;
```

It returns 2, but this:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(QUARTER, DATE_FORMAT('2018-03-31', '%Y-%m-%d'), DATE_FORMAT('2018-09-30', '%Y-%m-%d'))
FROM DUAL;
```

It returns 1.

Now I want the second returns 2 too, because March in quarter 1 and September in quarter 3, I just want it return 3-1=2.

I use this now:

```
SELECT (YEAR('2018-09-30') - YEAR('2018-03-31')) * 4 + (QUARTER('2018-09-30') - QUARTER('2018-03-31'))
FROM DUAL;
```

Is it the right way to do this? and how to do this right please?

Comment: Use the beginning of the quarter instead of the end.  That will insulate your from end-of-month issues.

Comment: Thank you. I use SELECT DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-', ELT(QUARTER(CURDATE()), 1, 4, 7, 10), '-', 1)) FROM DUAL; to get the beginning of the quarter.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the correct answer just using the `QUARTER()` function:

```
SELECT QUARTER('2018-09-30') - QUARTER('2018-03-31') AS QuarterDifference
FROM DUAL;

QuarterDifference
-----------------
2
```

Here's a demo of this: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2bccf9/1)

Comment: Thank you. but like I said, the time columns are not all in the same year.